# How to calculate objects velocity after ataching to surface with a pole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity

How do I calculate object's velocity after it has attached it self to a surface with a stick (by stick I mean it is not a spring or rope, it does not bend)? I need it for the video game I am making.

[image]

Initially the black box's has velocity as represented with red arrow (vector (speedx, speedy)). Then it is attached to the white surface with unelastic not bending stick at angle B (stick's length does not change). How to calculate the new velocity of the box at that moment?

Comment: You just need to compute the component of the initial velocity that acts perpendicularly to the rod.

Comment: @lemon I came up with `speedx = |v| * cosB * cosB` and `speedy = |v| * sinB * cosB`, where v is initial velocity vector. I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial speed (red arrow) is $\vec{u}=(u_x,u_y)$ then the new speed is:

$$ \vec{v} = \vec{u} - (\vec{u}\cdot\hat{l})\hat{l} $$

where $\hat{l}=(-\sin \beta,\cos\beta)$ (I'm assuming that the $\beta$ in your diagram is positive).

Plugging this in gives
\begin{align}
v_x &= u_x + k\sin\beta \\
v_y &= u_y - k\cos\beta
\end{align}
where
$$ k=u_y\cos\beta - u_x\sin\beta $$

(You can validate this by computing $\vec{v}\cdot\hat{l}=0$)